# How to merge two objects which having same key names in jquery?

Tags: jquery, object

I have two objects

**Object1**

```
0: {count: "100", keyFrom: "2"}
1: {count: "200", keyFrom: "4"}
2: {count: "300", keyFrom: "8"}
```

**Object2**

```
0: {count: "400", keyFrom: "3"}
1: {count: "500", keyFrom: "9"}
2: {count: "600", keyFrom: "7"}
3: {count: "700", keyFrom: "1"}
4: {count: "900", keyFrom: "5"}
```

I want to merge these two objects. I tried using

```
var objects = {};
$.extend(objects, object1, object2);
```

But this gives me a result like,

```
0: {count: "100", keyFrom: "2"}
1: {count: "200", keyFrom: "4"}
2: {count: "300", keyFrom: "8"}
3: {count: "700", keyFrom: "1"}
4: {count: "900", keyFrom: "5"}
```

It omits the first three values in `object2`.
But I want to merge like,

```
0: {count: "100", keyFrom: "2"}
1: {count: "200", keyFrom: "4"}
2: {count: "300", keyFrom: "8"}
3: {count: "400", keyFrom: "3"}
4: {count: "500", keyFrom: "9"}
5: {count: "600", keyFrom: "7"}
6: {count: "700", keyFrom: "1"}
7: {count: "900", keyFrom: "5"}
```

Help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Are they arrays, or non-array objects?

Comment: It looks like these are two arrays containing objects. So you can just use concat?

Comment: three key are not updating bz json object cannot have duplicte keys,so key 0,1,2 is already present in the first object so it will take again from the second object.

Comment: check out my answer bro it might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're arrays, just use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
var new_object = object1.concat(object2);
```

Live Example:

```js
var object1 = [
    {count: "100", keyFrom: "2"},
    {count: "200", keyFrom: "4"},
    {count: "300", keyFrom: "8"}
];
var object2 = [
    {count: "400", keyFrom: "3"},
    {count: "500", keyFrom: "9"},
    {count: "600", keyFrom: "7"},
    {count: "700", keyFrom: "1"},
    {count: "900", keyFrom: "5"}
];

var new_object = object1.concat(object2);
console.log(new_object);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If they're non-array objects with those property names and you want an array as a result, you can use the newish [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) (which can be polyfilled) and spread notation (ES2015+) or `Array.prototype.push.apply` (ES5):

```
var new_object = Object.values(object1);
new_object.push(...Object.values(object2));
```

or

```
var new_object = Object.values(object1);
Array.prototype.push.apply(new_object, Object.values(object2));
```

Live Example:

```js
var object1 = {
    0: {count: "100", keyFrom: "2"},
    1: {count: "200", keyFrom: "4"},
    2: {count: "300", keyFrom: "8"}
};
var object2 = {
    0: {count: "400", keyFrom: "3"},
    1: {count: "500", keyFrom: "9"},
    2: {count: "600", keyFrom: "7"},
    3: {count: "700", keyFrom: "1"},
    4: {count: "900", keyFrom: "5"}
};

var new_object = Object.values(object1);
new_object.push(...Object.values(object2));
// Or in ES5 with an `Object.values` polyfill
// Array.prototype.push.apply(new_object, Object.values(object2));
console.log(new_object);
```

If they're non-array objects with those property names and you want a non-array object with similar property names, you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (which is the built-in version of `$.extend` in ES2015+) or `$.extend` afterward:

```
var new_object = Object.values(object1);
new_object.push(...Object.values(object2));
new_object = Object.assign({}, new_object);
```

```js
var object1 = {
    0: {count: "100", keyFrom: "2"},
    1: {count: "200", keyFrom: "4"},
    2: {count: "300", keyFrom: "8"}
};
var object2 = {
    0: {count: "400", keyFrom: "3"},
    1: {count: "500", keyFrom: "9"},
    2: {count: "600", keyFrom: "7"},
    3: {count: "700", keyFrom: "1"},
    4: {count: "900", keyFrom: "5"}
};

var new_object = Object.values(object1);
new_object.push(...Object.values(object2));
new_object = Object.assign({}, new_object);
console.log(new_object);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sir, `var new_object = Array.prototype.concat.call(data.experienceList.experienceTo, data.experienceList.experienceFrom);` is working for me

Comment: @selva - Interesting. I removed that from my answer because what it created didn't look like what you wanted. But if it does, great!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert them to arrays and merge:

```
var array1 = $.map(object1, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});
var array2 = $.map(object2, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});
var result = $.merge($.merge([], array1, array2);
```

Or even simpler, combining with the previous answer:

```
var result = $.merge($.merge([], Object.values(object1)), Object.values(object2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use it in a array only then you can concat as u need.please refer the below code

```js
let x = [{count: "100", keyFrom: "2"} ,{count: "200", keyFrom: "4"},{count: "300", keyFrom: "8"}];
let y = [{count: "400", keyFrom: "3"},{count: "500", keyFrom: "9"},{count: "600", keyFrom: "7"},
         {count: "700", keyFrom: "1"},{count: "900", keyFrom: "5"}];
console.log(x.concat(y));
```